# Button on top of Anchor - How to prevent Default click?

Tags: html, button, preventdefault

I have a button on top of an anchor (image)

I have an alert for each (the button and the anchor).

After I click the button, the anchor then follows with its alert too. How do I prevent the anchor from initiating after I click the button?

see jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/EhWZc/

HTML:

```
<a href='#' onclick='alert("Im an anchor");'>
   <button id='delBtn' onclick="alert('Im a button');">x</button>
   <img src='http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg' style='width:200px;'/>
</a>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are nesting a button in an anchor tag to begin with? It if firing because the button is a child of anchor. You could make the anchor return false but the general idea is strange in the first place

Comment: Its for a bigger project. I'm using fancybox - when the user clicks on the thumbnail image, the large size photo appears. I'm trying to revise it such that when user performs a "mouseover", the "x" button will appear and allow user to delete image. So there is a purpose to have the anchor clicked because the plugin requires an img nested inside an anchor

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to use stopPropagation function instead of preventDefault like below.

```
 $('#delBtn').on('click', function(e){                   
        e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/EhWZc/1/)